# Termite leaving sand on wall

Tags: walls, sanding, new-home

We have termites problem in our house. And its getting worse day by day. We keep cleaning the wall everyday but still the problem of this sand termite exist. Please if anyone know how to keep them away please help me. And tell me what should we do to fill those holes

Comment: You should contact a local reputable exterminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning your walls won't help; you're only taking away the crud your termites output.

Filling in the holes won't make a difference to the original problem of termites eating away at your structure. This might make things look good, but stuff is rotting away deep inside, and no amount of lipstick can fix that.

Please call an exterminator. That's certainly more expensive than just covering up the damage, but if you want your home to stay structurally sound and livable, you'll need to repair whatever damage has already occurred.

EDIT: Your profile indicates you aren't in a wood-framed house, in which case my answer would probably not apply at all. You'll need to figure out what your termites are after (wood, other food), and remove that attractant. Calling an exterminator may still help.

Comment: its around the wooden materials. but anyway thanks for your answer it was really helpful because i was tired of cleaning the wall.

Comment: Termites also love moisture, so cleaning the walls may actually be making the infestation worse as you are giving them more moisture every time you wet down the walls.